# What will happen if the solar system leaves the milky way galaxy?

Tags: astrophysics, solar-system, milky-way

Is the milky way galaxy meaningful to us? Will any bad thing happen if the solar system just leaves the galaxy?

Comment: I can't imagine whatever caused the solar system to fly out of the galaxy would have had a positive effect on us.

Comment: This question might be more reasonable if you provide realistic mechanism by which our solar system leaves the galaxy. Without this, the question feels a bit too open-ended.

Comment: @BMS How about being ejected due to an interaction with another star. Whilst unlikely this cannot be ruled out. Premature closure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the short term, no, nothing bad will happen. The Milky Way is not particularly important to us in terms of keeping the solar system together, protecting us from anything dangerous, and so on. In fact it's probably slightly safer to leave:

- If the solar system is leaving the galaxy by natural causes, chances are we're a few billion years in the future and the Milky Way is colliding with Andromeda, and our star is one of those that happened to get gravitationally scattered/ejected from the system.
- This is actually probably for the best. At present there are no known nearby stars that are likely to explode as supernovae any time soon. A galaxy collision typically causes the formation of quite a large number of new stars, many of which will be the short lived hot type that go boom. If one happened to form fairly close to the Sun and we waited maybe 10 million years, this could be very bad for Earth.
- On the other hand the Sun is expected to burn out around the same time as the Milky Way collides with Andromeda, so being in the galaxy might be advantageous if we're still around... we might want to find a new home around another star. There are many more options in the galaxy than in the void of intergalactic space.

Other consequences of leaving the Milky Way:

- Some astronomers will be very happy. The Milky Way will no longer be in the way of a big chunk of the sky, making life much easier for them (I fall roughly into this category).
- Some other astronomers will be very annoyed, since they were trying to study the Milky Way and now it's getting more difficult to do so.
- The night sky will get a lot less spectacular, especially in the southern hemisphere (where you can look out toward the centre of the Milky Way). On the bright side, the Milky Way-Andromeda collision will be quite the firework show, so at least we'd get to see that before the view gets a bit more boring.

In response to comment on potential harmful radiation sources:

Much of the astronomically sourced radiation that is potentially dangerous to humans is actually from our own galaxy. All galaxies are dumping radiation into space, but ours being nearby is the dominant source. For instance, here is the sky in the ultraviolet (GALEX satellite); the orange is higher intensity (more info/maps [here](http://www.galex.caltech.edu/researcher/techdoc-ch2.html)):

[image: UV sky]

In X-rays (ROSAT satellite); most of the energy is coming from the blue/green regions:

[image: X-ray sky]

And $\gamma$-rays (Fermi satellite); red/yellow = higher intensity:

[image: gamma ray sky]

As you can see, there's one feature that is qualitatively similar in every map - there's a big band of emission horizontally across the middle. The images are oriented so that the galactic plane lies across the middle horizontally; our galaxy (and all galaxies) put out a lot of radiation. Rather than shielding us, being in a galaxy actually irradiates us *more*. It's a good thing our atmosphere does a pretty good job of attenuating radiation in most harmful wavelengths!

Of course in many wavelengths, the night sky is of secondary concern beside the Sun - which definitely puts out WAY more in the IR, optical and UV (you don't get a sunburn at night, after all), and has significant x-ray emission. I think the rest of the sky wins in gamma rays since the Sun doesn't have processes energetic enough to produce any. For the longer wavelengths (sub-mm/microwave/radio) I'm not sure off the top of my head whether most of the energy we receive is solar, galactic or cosmic in origin.

Comment: Not being an astronomer, I wouldn't know. But doesn't the Milky Way protect us from inter-galactic radiation and nasty stuff like that?

Comment: I am not an astronomer either, but my assumption is that inter-galactic radiation is way too weak and negligible in compared to the inner-galactic radiation which we're being bombarded with.

Comment: @Jim editing with some info on the topic :)

Comment: Like the edits. Great pictures. I'd imagine most of the microwave radiation is cosmic (CMB and whatnot). But my question originated from the following: Earth's magnetosphere protects us from some harmful Solar radiation. Sun's magnetosphere protects from some harmful Galactic radiation. I figured Galactic magnetosphere might protect from cosmic sources. Now that I think of it though, it seems silly to assume the Galaxy has a significant magnetosphere

Comment: Kyle I've nominated this for reopening and it has cropped up on Astronomy SE. But what is missing here is a discussion of what sort of interaction could lead to ejection and how might this disrupt the solar system. I rather fear that the rest of the discussion may be irrelevant.

Comment: Hopefully, also, we have moved off the Earth if we are talking a billion years or more from now. The Earth should be losing all of it's surface water by then.

Comment: @RobJeffries hmm well I don't think it's too hard to come up with a suitable interaction. And it's by no means given that the SS would be disrupted in such an ejection. This is a galaxy-galaxy collision. It's fairly common in such scenarios to basically rip off entire spiral arms. But the SS is quite tightly bound to the Sun, if my intuition is right we'd be fine.

Comment: @KyleOman To *escape* the Galaxy the Sun has to be given a kick  of at least a few hundred km/s.  Is the SS really going to be unaffected by a close encounter with a hard binary that might do this? I guess a more favourable mechanism would be with something that exerted smaller tides.

Comment: @RobJeffries scattering off a hard binary isn't really the right picture in a galaxy merger. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7HF5Oy8IMoM Some of the stars get really violent kicks, but many are "gently" ripped off.

Comment: This reinforces what I said. The small fraction of stars that escape the galaxies are ejected at very high velocities. Those that are not, do not get very far and fall back. The fate of a solar system would depend on how the high velocity was obtained.